# Covariates in machine learning classificatoin

Tags: machine-learning, classification, statistics, machine-learning-model

I would like to classify a number of people as sick and healthy. I have all the body measures as features. I have to control for age and sex because body features are affected by that. How do I adjust for age and sex?
Should I just add all the variables including age and sex as variables and try to classify? Or, should I do something else?

Answer (score 2):

As a classification task, you should add age and sex as features to your classifier in addition to your body measures. This will incorporate to be considered when learning or making a prediction. 
So your first option would be reasonable.